Why is ListView performing better than ArrayList
I encountered an issue while customizing UDAF using Flink (version 1.20). I wanted to implement a UDAF that calculates the median, and I used the following two methods:
public class MedianUDAF2 extends AggregateFunction<Double, MedianUDAF2.State> {

    public static class State {

        public int scale = 2;

        public ListView<Double> numbers;

        public State() {}
    }

    @Override
    public State createAccumulator() {
        State state = new State();
        state.numbers = new ListView<>();
        return state;
    }

    public void accumulate(State acc, Double val, Integer scale) throws Exception {
        acc.numbers.add(val);
        if (scale != null && scale > 0) acc.scale = scale;
    }

    public void merge(State acc, Iterable<State> it) throws Exception {
        for (State a : it) {
            acc.numbers.addAll(a.numbers.getList());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Double getValue(State acc) {
        try {
            List<Double> numbers = acc.numbers.getList();
            numbers.sort(Double::compareTo);
            double n = numbers.size() - 1;
            double index = n * 0.5;

            int low = (int) Math.floor(index);
            int high = (int) Math.ceil(index);

            double value = low == high ? (numbers.get(low) + numbers.get(high)) * 0.5 : numbers.get(high);
            BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal(value);
            return decimal.setScale(acc.scale, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).doubleValue();
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
        return 0.0;
    }
}

public class MedianUDAF extends AggregateFunction<Double, MedianUDAF.State> {

    public static class State {

        public int scale = 2;

        @DataTypeHint(value = "ARRAY<DOUBLE>")
        public ArrayList<Double> numbers;

        public State() {}
    }

    @Override
    public State createAccumulator() {
        State state = new State();
        state.numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        return state;
    }

    public void accumulate(State acc, Double val, Integer scale) throws Exception {
        acc.numbers.add(val);
        if (scale != null && scale > 0) acc.scale = scale;
    }

    public void merge(State acc, Iterable<State> it) throws Exception {
        for (State a : it) {
            acc.numbers.addAll(a.numbers);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Double getValue(State acc) {
        try {
            List<Double> numbers = acc.numbers;
            numbers.sort(Double::compareTo);
            double n = numbers.size() - 1;
            double index = n * 0.5;

            int low = (int) Math.floor(index);
            int high = (int) Math.ceil(index);

            double value = low == high ? (numbers.get(low) + numbers.get(high)) * 0.5 : numbers.get(high);
            BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal(value);
            return decimal.setScale(acc.scale, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).doubleValue();
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
        return 0.0;
    }
}

tableEnvironment.createTemporarySystemFunction("median", new MedianUDAF()); // Or new MedianUDAF2()
Table table = tableEnvironment.sqlQuery("select median(l_linenumber, 2) from lineitem");

Their difference lies in the fact that one uses an ArrayList and the other uses a ListView in State, and their performance gap is very large. Why ?
The comments on the ListView state that it will use a state backend in large amounts of data. Before Flink-table-planner 1.14, the addAccumulatorDataViews in AggregationCodeGenerator could see this conversion process, but it is no longer visible in version 1.20,
I tried to DEBUG this conversion process in the AggsHandlerCodeGenerator class, but still couldn't succeed,
May I ask where this conversion process occurred and how I should observe this phenomenon? Thank you, thank you!!!

Are you using the RocksDB state backend?

@DavidAnderson No, I'm not sure if this change is due to the need for status storage in the ListView,

I found that this issue is only related to the streaming or batch mode, and there is no problem with setting the streaming mode to execute.

ListView looks like a Java class but is actually an interface. Whenever possible it goes directly against Flink‘s state backend.
This will improve the performance for get requests esp. on large lists. Instead of accessing the entire list when calling accumulate(), list elements are accessed lazily. Thus, deserialization happens lazily and only on the accessed elements and not the full list.
